# Django PostgreSQL Deadlocks with Multiprocessing

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, multiprocessing

I am running a Django application that calculates and stores a bunch of stats about one table in another table while keeping M2M links between the two. To generate the stats table, I have set up a multiprocessing system that queries everything from table 1 and loads it into table 2. However, when I run my queries on many processors simultaneously, I get deadlock errors (even when I turn on auto commit).

My stats table looks like the following:

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField(...)
    objects_from_table_1 = models.ManyToManyField('table_1', related_name='stats', ...)
```

And my parsing code looks like the following (happening simultaneously in many separate processes that have their own connections to the database)

```
for table1_object in table1_objects:
    for stat_obj in stat_objs:
        stat_obj.objects_from_table_1.add(table1_object)
        stat_obj.save()
```

I get the deadlock error when I try to save the object. I believe that what is happening is there is a lock because multiple processes are trying to add a table1_object to the same stat_obj simultaneously, which is creating a deadlock.

Is there some way that I can have the system wait for the lock to resolve itself or restructure my parsing code so that this deadlock does not occur?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while, we decided to simply save what the inputs were supposed to be for the stat_obj and then run through a list of stat_objs later -- that way, each stat_obj would only be modified by one thread at any given time.